# semibold Linux Libertine broken?

Tags: errors, pdftex, bold, libertine

I've just updated to the latest TeX Live (on a Mac, i.e. `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` says `no updates available`) and am now getting errors when trying to use semibold fonts with the `libertine` package.  My MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[semibold]{libertine}
\begin{document}
no body needed
\end{document}
```

When compiling (with PDF LaTeX) I get the output below.  `texdoc libertine` still suggests that this is the correct way of getting semibold text, so don't think this option has been depreciated.

Any clues appreciated!

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \libertine@semibold
                               true
l.210 \ProcessOptionsX\relax

? ^D
! Emergency stop.
<argument> \libertine@semibold
                               true
l.210 \ProcessOptionsX\relax

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: Looks like a bug (there seems to be an unwanted space between bold and true) so make a bug report to the author.

Comment: The sty uses in two places `\@nameuse{\libertine@semibold#1}` instead of `\@nameuse{libertine@semibold#1}`.

Comment: great, thanks @UlrikeFischer!  I've sent an email to Bob and hacked my style file to change the above and it appears to do what I'd expect now.

Comment: this bug has now been fixed by the author and updated packages are available on CTAN (also available in TeXLive updates)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because fixed in current versions (as reported by OP)